# How can I create a python AWS Lambda function using the AWS CLI?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to create a simple lambda function in Python

This seems example for NodeJS but looking for a Python version..

```
aws lambda create-function --function-name helloworld \
--zip-file fileb://function.zip --handler index.handler --runtime nodejs8.10 \
--role arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/lambda-cli-role
{
    "FunctionName": "helloworld",
    "CodeSize": 351,
    "MemorySize": 128,
    "FunctionArn": "function-arn",
    "Handler": "index.handler",
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/LambdaExecRole",
    "Timeout": 3,
    "LastModified": "2015-04-07T22:02:58.854+0000",
    "Runtime": "nodejs8.10",
    "Description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same CLI options but specify the python runtime as well as include a python application in zip file format.

```
aws lambda create-function --function-name helloworld \
--zip-file fileb://test.zip \
--handler lambda_function.lambda_handler \
--runtime python3.7 \
--role arn:aws:iam::XXXX:role/CustomLambdaRoleARN 

CLI Output:
{
   "FunctionName": "helloworld",
   "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:XXXXXX:function:helloworld",
   "Runtime": "python3.7",
   "Role": "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:role/CustomLambdaRoleARN",
   "Handler": "lambda_function.lambda_handler",
   "CodeSize": 236,
   "Description": "",
   "Timeout": 3,
   "MemorySize": 128,
   "LastModified": "2019-04-23T04:25:33.052+0000",
   "CodeSha256": "5Gm3xdLGxELEIboaATKL7pr4sxrjNV1kuT9l9kpFG0g=",
   "Version": "$LATEST",
   "TracingConfig": {
       "Mode": "PassThrough"
   },
   "RevisionId": "3f18add5-d347-4754-83e5-61dfdeabda9a"
```

If you need help building a lambda application zip file, see this walk through. 
https://geektopia.tech/post.php?blogpost=Create_Lambda_Package_Python